# See the email reputation score for our public mailinglists?

Tags: email, spam

My organization hosts a couple dozen mailing lists using Mailman. Some of our emails are being tagged as spam by several providers (Google Apps) and many sites which use email appliances (Ironports).

We're looking to make some minor optimizations to increase our email reputation score among some of these providers.

Is there a central service which will show how our email is scored by some of the major providers and appliances? We don't actually need specific scores for Yahoo, Gmail or Hotmail. I'm looking for something more generic.

A Google search reveals some scoring providers, but I'm not sure which of these are reputable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup your ip blocks reputation on the ironport senderbase system. http://www.senderbase.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test). It will tell you some ways using which you can increase your Email reputation.